# h1 span is not rotate when using transform query

Tags: css

I have a `h1` heading with `span`. The `h1 span` element is to rotate 45 deg. but it's not.

HTML

```
<h1> i have to go <span class="rotate">From</span> here </h1>
```

CSS

```
.rotate{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

It's not working.

Comment: in which browser you are trying.?

Comment: @TMDinesh - Look at CitizenDelta answer for all browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give either `display: block` or `display: inline-block`:

```
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yeah...`inline-block` is better...no linebreaks

Answer (score 2):

You should add a "display: inline-block" property and don't forget to add ms and webkit compatibility :)

```
.rotate{
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fh64nw9/)

Comment: @TMDinesh - Look at CitizenDelta answer for all browsers

Answer (score 0):

**It's working you are having other issue**

```css
.working{
    transform:rotate(45deg);  
    margin-top:300px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="working">hello see it's working</h1>
```